# Perl script to chop input and start a new line after a certain number of instances

Tags: command-line, text-processing, perl

I have a perl script to convert a text file to json.
The script looks like this:

```
perl -MJSON -F, -lane '
    print to_json ({
           domain => shift @F,
           emails => [map {{email =>$_}} @F]
           }, {canonical=>1})
' input1.txt' > output.json
```

This script writes the output to a file in JSON format.
I want to know how I can modify the script to chop the input as well.
Here's an example:
The input file contains something like the following:

```
example.com,1@example.com,2@example.com,3@example.com,4@example.com,....
```

The output JSON file will be:

```
{"domain":"example.com",emails:[{email:"1@example.com"},{email:"2@example.com"},.....]}
```

The dot(.) means there are other emails getting added there after.

Now what I want to have is, if the email exceeds 21, then the script should write to a new line in the output file

Input file:

```
example.com,1@example.com,2@example.com,3@example.com,4@example.com,....500@example.com
```

Output should be:

```
{"domain":"example.com",emails:[{email:"1@example.com"},{email:"2@example.com"},.....,{email:21@example.com}]}
{"domain":"example.com",emails:[{email:"22@example.com"},{email:"23@example.com"},.....]}
{"domain":"nextdomain.com",emails:[{email:"1@nextdomain.com"},{email:"2@nextdomain.com"},.....]}
```

And the process continues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [splice](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/docs/perldoc/functions/splice.html) to remove the first 21 elements of the array in a loop:

```
perl -MJSON -F, -lane '
    $domain = shift @F;
    while (@f = splice @F, 0, 21) {
        print to_json ({
           domain => $domain,
           emails => [ map { { email => $_ } } @f ]
        }, { canonical => 1 });
    }
'
```